# Integrals over Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am performing lots of simple calculations with dirac delta functions.
For example, this integral:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x^(2) - y^(2)] x^4, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I get the answer:

```
(y^4 (Boole[-\[Infinity] < -y < \[Infinity]] + Boole[-\[Infinity] < y < \[Infinity]]))/(2 Abs[y])
```

Another example:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[sin (x)] E^(-x), {x, -1, Infinity}]
```

Mathematica shows the answer:

```
ConditionalExpression[1/Abs[sin], sin \[Element] Reals]
```

There is a way of calculating such integrals by using Mathematica?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: sin (x) is not the same as Sin[x] -- you probably mean the latter.

Comment: Up to Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function , Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[x]] E^(-x), {x, -1, Infinity}] has no sense so MMA 11.3correctly returns it unevaluated.

Comment: @user64494: I believe the integral evaluates to `Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[x]] E^(-x), {x, -1, Infinity}]==Sum[Exp[-n Pi],{n,0,Infinity}]==E^\[Pi]/(-1 + E^\[Pi]) `.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: See the excuted code saved as a PDF file https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c7rncjs8mp94bh/Dirac.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Have you read the Wiki article cited above, especially "Composition with a function", before posting your comment?

Comment: @user64494: Thank you for your feedback. I read wikipedia link and feel confirmed.  Unfortunately I can't use dropbox-link.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: First, your statement is unbased. Second, here is the executed nb file https://www.dropbox.com/s/jczsf7j0m6krui5/Dirac.nb?dl=0 .

Comment: @user64494: As I mentioned, I can't use dropbox! Wikipedia gives the composition I used to get my result(similar to the answer `bill s`)...

Comment: Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: You need not Dropbox to see these files.

Comment: @user64494: Remarkable appearance! Why didn't you publish your dropbox-files (which I cannot open!!!) as an answer, instead of feedback like "statement is unbased"  , "I still read empty words of you" ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to be explicit about your assumptions, and careful about syntax. For the first integral, you are most likely assuming that y is real, and you need to let Mathematica know that:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x^2 - y^2] x^4, {x,-Infinity,Infinity},
          Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals]

Abs[y]^3/2
```

Correcting the syntax on the second integral does not allow evaluation:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[x]] Exp[-x], {x, -1, Infinity}]
```

By the sifting property of DiracDelta, I guess this is equal to the infinite sum:

```
Sum[Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity, Pi}]

E^\[Pi]/(-1 + E^\[Pi])
```

which does evaluate nicely.

Comment: Bei careful. First, one should try to remove `Sin[x]` by substitution.

Comment: Up to Wiki en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function , Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[x]] E^(-x), {x, -1, Infinity}] has no sense so MMA 11.3correctly returns it unevaluated.

Comment: @user64494 there's literally formula for this case in the page you linked.

Comment: @Vsevolod A.: Are you serious? Read carefully the "Composition with a function" section there.

Comment: @user64494 absolutely serious.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the formula `DiracDelta[g[x]] == Sum[DiracDelta[x - xi]/Abs[g'[xi] ]]` where the `xi` are the roots of `g[x]` and the sum is over all the roots.

In this case:

```
g[x_]=Sin[x]
```

and the roots of `Sin[x]` are.

```
xi=n Pi
```

So by the formula we have for the integral in question

```
Sum[Integrate[DiracDelta[x-xi]/Abs[g'[x]/.x->xi]Exp[-x],{x,-1,Infinity}],{n,0,Infinity}]

(*E^Pi/(E^Pi - 1)*)
```

which matches bill s and Ulrich Neumann results.

It seems like MMA should be able to do this directly.